# All migration files and Records was deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

I did a big mistake with my project

i'm using EF 6.0 for my project in C# with manual migrations.
 for some reasons i deleted all migration files from my project and all migration records from `__MigrationHistory` table.

i want to add a new `migration` to update the database with the new changes (many changes) on data model entities.

i don't want to lose my data. so i cannot delete my database and create another one.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better solution, but this could help:

1. Rename your existing database.
2. Add a new migration, it will create a new database.
3. Use the SqlServer Tools of Visual Studio, and compare the schema of the New Database to the Old Database.
4. Use the SqlServer Tools of Visual Studio, and compare the data of the New Database to the Old Database (Copy the migration history table).
5. Delete the new database.
6. Rename the Old Database using its previous name.

It should be done for all developers.